# How are computed linear predictors in R glm probit?

Tags: r, glm

I would like to understand how linear.predictors are computed in the output of

```
pb = glm(formula, family = binomial( link = "probit" ), data)
```

From my understanding, it should be the product matrix of the observations (N x k) and the estimated coefficients (k x 1), with N = sample size, k = number of variables.

I tried to compute them by hand in two fashions:

```
rowSums(mapply(`*`,pb$model,pb$coefficients))
```

and

```
as.matrix(pb$model)%*%as.matrix(pb$coefficients)
```

Both gave me the same vector of values that equals `pb$linear.predictors` for some observations but not all.

Could you help me understand how it is computed and how I could reproduce it by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it's better to use *accessor methods*, if they're available, then internal components of the model (accessed via `$`, or `@` for S4 objects); internal components can be poorly documented/surprising and/or subject to change (although the latter is unlikely for a foundational component of R like a `glm` object).

```r
model.matrix(pb) %*% coef(pb)
```

should work to compute the linear predictor for a wide range of model types.

To follow up on @nrennie's answer: the first column of the model frame was probably the response variable, while the first element of the coefficient vector is the intercept. *If* the response was 1.0, then you would correctly add the intercept term to the model. (The model **matrix**, as opposed to the model **frame**, has a first column composed entirely of ones ...)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the output of `pb$model` you'll see this also includes the outcome, `y`, and you don't want to multiply by the outcome to get predicted values.

Try:

```r
as.matrix(pb$model[, -1])%*%as.matrix(pb$coefficients[-1]) + pb$coefficients[1]
```

Remove the outcome column from `pb$model`, and remove the intercept from the coefficients. Then multiply the matrices and add the intercept back in.

You could alternatively replace the first column of `pb$model` with a column of `1`s and multiply by `pb$coefficients`. This is the approach that follows matrix notation if you look up linear algebra for regression.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with @Ben Bolker's solution as it is more concise but you provide a great answer on WHY I was wrong.